# How to create dynamic required parameter

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm making chatbot with Dialogflow using console and client library api.

I created entity(Composite entity) that have a location data.

And I have a intent using my custom location entity as a required parameter.

That entity consists of 3entities(each entities is map entity)

**Like this:**

**@step1:step1**

**@step2:step2**

**@step3:step3**

**United States(step1), New York(step2), xxx(step3)**

**(The next step, the smaller the area.)**

And if User typed only one step, have to next step.

**So far, example scenario is:**

**Agent: Please type location**

**User: New York**

Then, Return some data by querying the database using location data.

But if many step1 data has New York(step2), I want to listup step1 and show user it as a required parameter.

**What I want is:**

**Agent: Canada, UK, US has a New York, Please select one.**

**User: Canada**

So, I want to create dynamic required parameter, like above case.

Is there any good idea for solve this problem?

It's okay if it's not a way to implement the required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to should create [dynamic response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-responses#fulfillment).

When you follow the documentation to [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview). There is example there:

> For example, if an end-user wants to schedule a haircut on Friday,
> your service can check your database and respond to the end-user with
> availability information for Friday.

So this is very similar to your use case, when you get "New York" you have to query for possible choices. You have to follow this documentation.

Comment: Yes, I already create dynamic response with client library API.

What I want is,when I get "New York", return the query result functionally like "required parameter".

I can simply return the list But after return, I have to code to check it.

Like this:  

If user_input in list_has_newyork:

...

else:  

wirte Re-question code//  

I think  this way will make code dirty and inefficient.

I'm a beginner, so I think I'm more likely to be wrong.

What should I do to make it function like "required parameter"?

Comment: What do you mean "function like required parameter"?

Comment: "function like required parameter" means, remember the intent that include "required parameter" and keep asking until user answer about "required parameter".
If I return the list(that has "newyork" as a step2) as a dynamic response, Dialogflow agent consider user's next answer is a new question, not answer about most recently detected intent's required parameter.

Comment: "required parameter" persist context until user answered about "required parameter".
I don't know that how can I code that function.
If the way that code by playing with the context is only way, should you advice me how to implement that function with code?

Comment: To be honest I am still not sure what is on your mind, so I cannot reproduce it. I think the best will be to try do some coding and if it wont work, present your try to community,